# How do i bind the "contextmenu"(it is a Plugin for the Context menu) to every first td in every row

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

iam having the table with id "someTable" where i have the rows dynamically from PHP 
i want to apply the contextmenu to every first td in every row .iam using the 
context menu  plugin from here (http://www.trendskitchens.co.nz/jquery/contextmenu/)

```
        $("someTable td").contextmenu('mymenu')(function (){

    //would the above statement work
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/):

```
$("#someTable td:first-child")
```

`:first-child` will select all matching elements (the tds) that are the first child of their parent (the tr).

Comment: What "function" Should i use  if i want to apply for every row in the table

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector like this:

```
$("someTable td:nth-child(1)")
```

That will target every first `td` of the row.